# Viewcontroller.h File Instead of View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a project in Xcode 8 in which I am using one view controller when i try to add another view controller i get a viewcontroller.h which i cannot edit or unlock. Why is this happening? Can I use more than one View Controller in a project? If you know how to create another View Controller please answer.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you added an objective-c file instead of a swift file.  Delete the .h file and add another view controller, making sure to select 'swift' as the language.

Comment: and how could i connect a storyboard to view controller?

Comment: You've tagged your question with Swift.  Are you using Objective-c or Swift?  Also, I'm guessing you're new to iOS development based on your question.  You can have more than 1 view controller in a project but they can't be named the same.  I recommend you find a good beginners tutorial to follow first.  That will answer your questions and show you how to do what you want to do in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many viewcontrollers in project as long as you name them uniquely. Follow the steps:
1) Right click on folder in which you want to create a viewcontroller
2) Select New File option 
3) In the "Choose a template for your view file" select  source in ios & click on "cocoa touch class" --> tap Next
4)In next window Enter "Class" which will be name of your new view controller & in "Subclass of" make sure you select "UIViewController" class. Select "Language" as Objective-c & then click Next
5) In next window click "create" button

That is all you have to do.